# Does SharedPreferences listener detect external changes?

Tags: android, security, sharedpreferences, root

I'm implementing an app in which use of SharedPreferences is quite critical in terms of security. I've declared them as `MODE_PRIVATE`, but even in that case I'm worried that in a device with root permissions it could be changed by manually accesing the file the SharedPreferences are stored in.

I'm thinking of using a OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener, but I don't know if it also detects changes made manually on the file or it only is used when the modification is made via code. Does anyone knows it? Otherwise, is there any other way to detect when the file is changed?

Thank you so much in advance for your help. Please, don't hesitate to ask me if more details are needed or if I haven't been clear enough.

Comment: "I don't know if it also detects changes made manually on the file" -- AFAIK, it does not. This is why even the now-discontinued multiple-process support for `SharedPreferences` did not work well, because one process would not necessarily detect the other process' changes. Beyond that, if you are worried about rooted device users, then do not store the data on the device.

Comment: In modern Android versions it does not directly detect changes made by other apps. For that you have to restart the app. It does not even detect some changes made by the app itself. For instance you could replace the whole file with another file. It looks as if the app has buffered the whole file. So also here you have to restart first. I used to exchange complete xml files for different users of an app and had to change the approach.

Comment: I will suggest if you worried about the security and integrity of the files, try to encrypt and decrypt the values/files before saving into or reading from the sharePreference.